# Добавление класса первым элементам

Tags: jquery, классы

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать, чтобы класс добавлялся только первым 3-ем элементам?

```
<div id="rating_1">
 <span class="serv_rate"></span>
 <span class="serv_rate"></span>
 <span class="serv_rate"></span>
 <span class="serv_rate"></span>
 <span class="serv_rate"></span>
</div>
```

---

```
var i = 3;
while(i <= fullStars){
    $('#rating_' + id + ' .serv_rate').addClass('smallstar');
    i++;
}
```

Сейчас получается, что класс добавляется ко всем элементам, а мне надо к 3-м.

Comment: `$('#rating_1 .serv_rate:lt(3)').addClass('smallstar')`

Comment: @RubaXa, а если там не 3, а переменную ставить, то 
"$('#rating_1' + id + ' .serv_rate:lt(' + i + ')').addClass('smallstar');"?

Comment: @wao138, вы перед тем как спросить, сначала сами попробовали, хотя бы для приличия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) *version added: 1.1.4*

```
$('#rating_1 .serv_rate').slice(0,3).addClass('smallstar');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/2bMSM/

Answer (score 2):

[@wao138](/users/19593/wao138), так все работает: http://jsfiddle.net/m3wnx/
Вопрос в другом, как именно вы это применяете.

Например, зачем вы пытаетесь добавлять класс к элементам в цикле?

```
var num = 4;
$('#rating_1 .serv_rate:lt('+num+')').addClass('smallstar');
```

Answer (score -1):

Еще можно через перебор:

```
$('#rating_' + id + ' .serv_rate').each( function(ind) {
    if (ind < 3) {
        $(this).addClass('smallstar');
    }
} );
```

и примерчик http://jsfiddle.net/grc9b/

Comment: @RubaXa, интересно чем он неуместен, и чем он не нравится )

Comment: Я бы вообще по привычке через цикл и `.eq()` делал.

Comment: @IVsevolod, потому что ваш ответ не дополняет мой. Дополнение, это что типа [этого][1]. Хотя ваш вариант и будет работать на маленьких объемах, но уместным его всё равно назвать нельзя. А  абсолютный победитель это  slice,  хоть всё это справедливо только для несоставного селектора.

[1]: http://jsperf.com/lt-selector-vs-slice/2

Comment: @RubaXa надо бы не забыть по этому поводу партсобрание собрать и отчитать тунеядца. Ишь, о больших объемах не подумал.

Comment: Но если задача будет стоять не только в добавлении класса, но и с какими-либо манипуляциями над первыми 3 элементами, то метод достаточно удобен. Но не суть, я вас понял ) по вашим критериям действительно -1 )

Comment: @RubaXa мне кажется для чистоты теста не надо было добавлять addClass :)